# Unusual rendering and copy-paste for the character 誤

Tags: unicode, fonts, cjk

I'm seeing somewhat unusual behavior around the rendering of 誤 in the browser (works across both Firefox and Chrome), which I'm having trouble explaining.

Specifically, check out the [Wiktionary page for 誤](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%AA%A4):

[image: Screenshot of Wiktionary showing variations of 誤]

Notice that there are 3 variations marked in black bold:

1. The top left one has 3 pieces: 言 + ⼝ + 天
2. The middle one kinda' has 4 pieces: 言 + ⼝ + a rotated ꒔ + ⼤
3. The bottom one has 3 pieces: ⻈ + ⼝ + 天

The relation between 2 and 3 is clear: 2 represents the traditional character and 1 represents the simplified character. But what does 1 represent? I've tried the following:

- I tried copying character 1 but when I paste it, it ends up looking like character 2.
- I tried various font combinations, both in the browser and in TextEdit, but the appearance and copy-pasting behavior persist.

So what is going on with this unusual character rendering and copy-pasting behavior? How can I reproduce character 1 (and not 2) in other applications?

FWIW, when I look at a [Chinese dictionary](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=1&wdqb=wudian), the stroke order shows character 2 even though the browser renders the character as 1.

[image: MDBG screenshot for 誤]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [z-variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-variant), and in this case probably an example of [Han unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification).

From https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%AA%A4:

[image]

You can see that the first character (marked as 内地 Mainland China) is what you're getting in the headword.

The headword on Wikipedia is formatted with `lang=zh`, whereas the example sentences use `zh-Hans` and `zh-Hant` respectively, and that's the core of this, along with likely subtags fallback.

Most systems dealing with locales perform locale fallback using [likely subtags](https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/38/supplemental/likely_subtags.html): So, `Hans` without any country specified typically implies `CN`, and `Hant` implies `TW` during fallback. The reverse is also true (and some other countries like HK imply `Hant` as well). `Hans`/`Hant` are script codes for Simplified and Traditional Chinese, and CN/TW are China and Taiwan respectively. `zh` on its own implies `zh-CN` (and thus `zh-Hans-CN`)

Fallback also need not always occur the same way, different fonts have different priorities (e.g. a Mainland Chinese font may assume CN by default unless explicitly told otherwise)

I made a little table, screenshot showing the rendering of different language tags on *my* system when run on Wikipedia (snippet at the bottom of this post)

[image]

The font's actually defaulting to Noto Sans CJK JP  unless I put it in a `class=Hant` context (where it switches to Noto Sans CJK TC).

What's happening under the hood is: traditional vs simplified is *not* unified in Unicode, but such variants *are*. Even though `zh` implies `zh-Hans-CN`, because this is a traditional character, the font will not use the `Hans` to pick a Simplified character: it *must* pick a traditional character since Simplified is encoded differently. So you get the Mainland Chinese traditional variant in `zh` contexts (like the headword), but since `zh-Hant` implies `zh-TW`, the font is happy to oblige and give you the Taiwanese (still traditional) variant in the example sentence.

Note that not all cases stick to a single font: sometimes the choice of language can force a different font to be selected (or the precise CSS used). Additionally, you can have z-variants crop up in different contexts without needing to change the language, for example the Cantonese possessive 嘅 can be built as ⿰口既 or ⿰口旣 and the choice is not clearly locale based and seems to vary freely between fonts.

---

Code for table above:

```html
<table>
 <tr lang=zh><td>zh</td><td>誤</td></tr>
 <tr lang=zh-Hans><td>zh-Hans</td><td>誤</td></tr>
 <tr lang=zh-Hant><td>zh-Hant</td><td>誤</td></tr>
 <tr lang=zh-CN><td>zh-CN</td><td>誤</td></tr>
 <tr lang=zh-Hant-CN><td>zh-Hant-CN</td><td>誤</td></tr>
 <tr lang=zh-Hans-CN><td>zh-Hans-CN</td><td>誤</td></tr>
 <tr lang=zh-TW><td>zh-TW</td><td>誤</td></tr>
 <tr lang=zh-HK><td>zh-HK</td><td>誤</td></tr>
 <tr lang=zh-Hans-TW><td>zh-Hans-TW</td><td>誤</td></tr>
 <tr lang=ja><td>ja</td><td>誤</td></tr>
 <tr lang=ko><td>ko</td><td>誤</td></tr>
 <tr lang=vi><td>vi</td><td>誤</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

(Based on a [Twitter discussion with manishearth](https://twitter.com/ManishEarth/status/1601436731945152512?s=20&t=zMCBN8YYmTepUng2-fP8jg))

The difference is coming up due to variations across fonts (called [z-variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-variant)). Specifically, based on the language tag, the browser can pick different fonts within the same font family (e.g. sans-serif). For example, on my device:

- With lang="zh", the browser picks PingFang SC from sans-serif.
- With lang="zh-Hant", the browser picks PingFang TC from sans-serif.

[image: PingFang TC]

[image: PingFang SC]

These two fonts render the character differently. The lang tag is different in different parts of the HTML, causing different font selection and hence different rendering.

Outside the browser, depending on the language context, the variant/language can also change. There is more discussion of this with examples on the [Han Unification Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification#Examples_of_language-dependent_glyphs).